# Merge objects according to id order in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve the order of this merged object. A object and B object are combined into one object, but note that the order is based on id.

I have two objects and merge objects, but I want to order according to id.

**The out put should be:**

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"apple"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"apple2"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name":"apple3"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "name":"apple4"
    }
]
```

My code:

```js
var a = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "apple"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "apple2"
  },

]
var b = [{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "apple3"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "apple4"
  }
]

const result = Object.assign(a, b);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge into one array with spread syntax, then sort by the `id` property:

```js
var a = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "apple"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "apple2"
  },

]
var b = [{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "apple3"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "apple4"
  }
]

const result = [...a, ...b]
  .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
console.log(result)
```

(if you know in advance that both input arrays already have their IDs in order, and you just need to fit the larger pieces together, then you can leave out the `.sort`, and just spread `a` followed by spreading `b`)

Comment: Or `a.concat(b).sort(...)` which is the same number of characters to type (and fewer if there are more that 2 arrays to concatenate). ;-)